# php destructor called too soon with fluent interface

Tags: php, mysql, destructor, fluent-interface

I found a really weird thing about php destructor:

basically I have a database management class which loads an adapter using a factory to define which adapter should be loaded (mysql, mysqli, etc.)

I'll write down only the part of the code insteresting, as the class itself is way longer but code isn't involved in the current trouble

The problem occurs ONLY with mysql (mysqli & pdo works just fine) but for compatibility purposes, getting rid of mysql it's out of question.

```
class manager
{
    private static $_instance;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        return isset(self::$_instance) ? self::$_instance : self::$_instance = new self;
    }

    public function getStandaloneAdapter()
    {
        return new mysql_adapter(array('host'=>'127.0.0.1', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'dbname' => 'etab_21'));
    }
}

abstract class abstract_adapter
{
    protected $_params;
    protected $_connection;

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        $this->_params = (object)$params;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo 'destructor<br/>';
        var_dump(debug_backtrace(false));
        $this->closeConnection();
    }

    abstract public function closeConnection();
}

class mysql_adapter extends abstract_adapter
{
    public function getConnection()
    {
        $this->_connect();

        if ($this->_connection) {
            // switch database
            $this->_useDB($this->_params->dbname);
        }

        return $this->_connection;
    }

    protected function _connect()
    {
        if ($this->_connection) {
            return;
        }

        // connect
        $this->_connection = mysql_connect(
            $this->_params->host,
            $this->_params->username,
            $this->_params->password,
            true
        );

        if (false === $this->_connection || mysql_errno($this->_connection)) {
            $this->closeConnection();
            throw new Mv_Core_Db_Exception(null, Mv_Core_Db_Exception::CONNECT, mysql_error());
        }

        if ($this->_params->dbname) {
            $this->_useDB($this->_params->dbname);
        }
    }

    private function _useDB($dbname)
    {
        return mysql_select_db($dbname, $this->_connection);
    }

    public function isConnected()
    {
        $isConnected = false;
        if (is_resource($this->_connection)) {
            $isConnected = mysql_ping($this->_connection);
        }
        return $isConnected;
    }

    public function closeConnection()
    {
        if ($this->isConnected()) {
            mysql_close($this->_connection);
        }
        $this->_connection = null;
    }
}
```

so here's the test i'm running:

```
$sadb1 = manager::getInstance()->getStandaloneAdapter()->getConnection();
var_dump($sadb1);
```

and the output i'm getting:

```
destructor
array
  0 => 
    array
      'file' => string '**\index.php' (length=48)
      'line' => int 119
      'function' => string '__destruct' (length=10)
      'class' => string 'abstract_adapter' (length=16)
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array
          empty
  1 => 
    array
      'file' => string '**\index.php' (length=48)
      'line' => int 119
      'function' => string 'unknown' (length=7)
resource(26, Unknown)
```

if i change my test to this:

```
$sadb1 = manager::getInstance()->getStandaloneAdapter();
var_dump($sadb1->getConnection());
```

the output is good:

```
resource(26, mysql link)
destructor
array
  0 => 
    array
      'function' => string '__destruct' (length=10)
      'class' => string 'abstract_adapter' (length=16)
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array
          empty
```

**wtf?!**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the first line in the `factory` function : `return new Mv_Core_Db_Adapter_Mysql...`?  Makes the rest of the function rather pointless.

Comment: i've edited my code, i've strip out any unnecessary lines and kept the minimum, still doesn't works x_x

Comment: During your test, are those the only two lines being used for the test other than the classes?  When using the `mysql` version, you say the `mysqli` and `pdo` work fine, within your code flow, what is the difference when using `mysql`?  Is it an unusual case and therefore with limited availability throughout the rest of the code?

Comment: Since you drastically cut down the code from when I first saw it to your actual problem, +1 for the research effort and a good question that I haven't seen before with regards to the Garbage Collection process. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The early destructor run in the first test is an outcome of automatic garbage collection. To understand this, let's look at the second (easier) test:

```
1. $db = Mv_Core_Db_Manager::getInstance();
2. $sadb = $db->getStandaloneAdapter('bdm_bcb');
3. var_dump($sadb->getConnection());
```

Steps:

1. the db manager is being assigned to the variable $db,
2. the standalone adapter (MySQL adapter in this case due to hack in the factory you have introduced for debugging) is being assigned to $sadb,
3. `var_dump()` debugs the return value of the `getConnection()` method of the $sadb standalone adapter, which is the `resource(29, mysql link)` line in your second output,
4. clean up time; PHP garbage collector runs the destructor for $sadb (visible in your output thanks to debug) and after that $db (not visible in your output).

Here garbage collection is hapenning at the end.

If you consider the first test you have described, despite deceivingly similar looking source code, it has different steps:

```
1. $db = Mv_Core_Db_Manager::getInstance();
2. $sadb = $db->getStandaloneAdapter('bdm_bcb')->getConnection();
3. var_dump($sadb);
```

Steps:

1. the same in the test case above,
2. the return value of the `getConnection()` getter of the MySQL standalone adapter object is assigned to $sadb,
3. because the MySQL standalone adapter itself has **not** been assigned to any variable, PHP garbage collector decides that it's not used anymore so it cleans up the object and runs its destructor (the destructor debug is visible in your output in first),
4. `var_dump()` debugs the value returned by the  of the `getConnection()` getter of the MySQL standalone adapter, which is basically a handle to a resource which has already been collected by the garbage collector.

Here garbage collection happens before `var_dump()`.

To summarize, the first test you have provided forces the garbage collector to jump in between lines 2 and 3 of your code. On the other hand, the second test forces the garbage collection at the very end.

The outcome is that your resource handle is pointing to memory that has been already cleaned up by the GC.

Comment: Very nice answer!  And welcome to SO.  Now go out and teach other new users to be more like you! ^^ +1

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code presented...

### PHP __destruct()

The [`__destruct()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) method, according to the documentation:

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

The reason that you would experience different results with:

```
$sadb1 = manager::getInstance()->getStandaloneAdapter()->getConnection();
var_dump($sadb1);
```

Giving you incorrect results (from what you are expecting) is that there are no more references to that `mysql_adapter` instance in your code, therefor the `__destruct()` method is called, doing so closes the reference to the `resource` that held the `mysql` link - as PHP5 is smart and passes most things auto-magically by reference (good thing - most of the time ^^), so when you `var_dump($sadb);`, the `__destruct` method was called on the previous line, so the `var_dump` gives you a reference, but now to nothing.

The reason this code gives you what you expect:

```
$sadb1 = manager::getInstance()->getStandaloneAdapter();
var_dump($sadb1->getConnection());
```

is that you dump the resource, and *then* the `__destruct` method is called, giving you the `debug_trace`, following the dump.

I hope that helps clear things up for you with regards to the destructor.

*Out of curiosity, why is `b` 'sad'? (`$sadb`) ^^*

Comment: bad coding habits from my developement team: we used to call the current adapter $db (database) so sometimes I keep using database word instead of adapter, so: sadb = StandAloneDataBase

Comment: Ahh.  And thank you for responding to my joke! =]  But that is a good explanation of why `b` would be sad, just based on the first three words of your response. ;)

Comment: I'm sorry I can't accept two answers, I've accepted the one that was more precise for future GC troubles :) yet your answer was correct and helped me too (and for your comment: totally ! :p)

Comment: No worries at all.  Besides, he's new to SO and provided a _damn good answer_, I wish more new users made answers like that. I'm glad you accepted his. =]