# PHP garbage collection when using static method to create instance

Tags: php, garbage-collection

After much tracking down I finally figured out what's going wrong in my code, so this question isn't "*how do I fix it*", but rather "*why does this happen?*".

**Consider the following code**:

```
class Foo {
    private $id;
    public $handle;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->handle = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');

        echo $this->id . ' - construct' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        echo $this->id . ' - destruct' . PHP_EOL;

        fclose($this->handle);
    }

    public function bar() {
        echo $this->id . ' - bar - ' . get_resource_type($this->handle) . PHP_EOL;

        return $this;
    }

    public static function create($id) {
        return new Foo($id);
    }
}
```

Seems simple enough - when created it will open up a memory stream and set the property `$handle` and `$id`. When destructing it will use `fclose` to close this stream.

**Usage**:

```
$foo = Foo::create(1); // works

var_dump( $foo->bar()->handle ); // works

var_dump( Foo::create(2)->bar()->handle ); // doesn't work
```

What seems to be the issue here is that I'm expecting both calls to return exactly the same but for some reason the `Foo::create(2)` call where I *don't* save the instance to a variable calls the garbage collector somewhere between the `return $this` part of the `bar()` method and me actually using the property `$handle`.

**In case you're wondering, *this* is the output**:

```
1 - construct                 // echo $this->id . ' - construct' . PHP_EOL;
1 - bar - stream              // echo $this->id . ' - bar - ' ...
resource(5) of type (stream)  // var_dump
2 - construct                 // echo $this->id . ' - construct' . PHP_EOL;
2 - bar - stream              // echo $this->id . ' - bar - ' ...
2 - destruct                  // echo $this->id . ' - destruct' . PHP_EOL;
resource(6) of type (Unknown) // var_dump
1 - destruct                  // echo $this->id . ' - destruct' . PHP_EOL;
```

**From what I can see this is what happens**:

```
var_dump( Foo::create(2)->bar()->handle );
// run GC before continuing..  ^^ .. but I'm not done with it :(
```

But *why*? Why does PHP think I'm done with the variable/class instance and hence feels the need to destruct it?

**Demos**:

[**eval.in demo**](https://eval.in/266758)
[**3v4l demo** (only HHVM can figure it out - all other PHP versions can't)](http://3v4l.org/NjpYP)

Comment: Maybe after the bar call the GC kills the object because it isn't assigned to a variable? I mean, it may have operations after the bar call but, as it isn't assigned to anything, it doesn't care and kills it off anyway.

Comment: @JamesHunt But it's still defined in the class (`$this->handle`) and it's returning the class instance (where `$instance->handle` is defined)?

Comment: Handle may be defined within the class, but the object itself still needs to be assigned to a variable for var_dump. var_dump is called with your argument, your argument uses the static function Foo::create(2) to create an instance of the class Foo, where you then use it's bar function. After the bar function is finished, the object itself isn't stored in a variable, it's just floating around as a possible argument, so maybe the GC is wiping it out before var_dump can get a hold of the handle variable?

Comment: @JamesHunt Following that logic, why does `Foo::create(2)->bar()` work? Why is this called before GC and `->handle` after GC? I can obviously still use the class (which is why I'm not getting an error when using `->handle`), but the destructor should first be called when it knows for sure that I'll never be able to use this again (because I destroyed it using `unset` or simply am done with the result).

Comment: I've a feeling GC is called whenever a function/method closes - without assigning your `new Foo` to anything it may well be cleaned up from memory during that sweep, I think @JamesHunt is right on this one. Singleton patterns work fine for instance as they assign the `new self()` to a static class member and are, therefore, stored in memory until the object itself is destroyed... I did read something weird about PHP and class members on here the other day that may have something to do with this... I'll see if I can dig it out.

Comment: @CD001 In that case, why does [`Foo::create(2)->bar()->bar()->bar()->bar()->bar()->handle` work for all the `bar()` calls?](https://eval.in/266786)

Comment: I *think* there's a weird quirk with how PHP deals with storing class data in memory that might cause this - but I can't remember what it is off the top of my head :|

Comment: Does `$newhandle = Foo:create(2)->bar()->handle;` work?

Comment: @JamesHunt [nope - `resource(5) of type (Unknown)`](https://eval.in/266819)

Comment: Maybe the handle argument becomes a reference to the handle variable within the object, once it's gotten that, the object is then destroyed by GC, which in your destructor closes the handle down. To test, make another variable within foo which is just an int or string, see if it passes it alright. If it does, then fantabbydosey, it's because your destructor is killing your handle before you can use it!

Comment: @JamesHunt I *know* the destructor is killing it before I can use it - that was proven by the output `2 - destruct` before the `var_dump` result. The question is why it would run when I still have access to the object (as proven by `->handle` working, albeit returning the post-destructed result).

Comment: After some playing around, I've come to the conclusion that this is a bit weird... if, in your create method you assign `new Foo()` to a variable and then return that variable it works fine too. `create($id) { $foo = new Foo($id); return $foo; }` then it's OK - even though the GC will destroy `$foo` at the close of the method (when $foo is returned). This may have something to do with the fact that constructors return null maybe - though I'm clutching at straws a bit here...

Comment: It also seems to work if you wrap some parentheses around it : `create($id) { return (new Foo($id)); }` - now I'm beginning to think this is to do with *class member access on instantiation* added in PHP 5.4 : http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Good finds. Though this code also works in < 5.4 (which is the exact reason I've used a static method rather than the function dereferencing)

Comment: Yah, really weird. It only happens with resources. If handle is a mysql connection, it will do the same thing -- but if it's a scalar, array, or object, it works.

Comment: FWIW, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163812/php-destructor-called-too-soon-with-fluent-interface) is a similar issue.

Comment: heh - it's not even what I previously thought - I *think* I've got it now ... maybe... what seems to be happening is that when `bar()` closes it destroys `$this` so unless you've already set `Foo::create($id);` to another variable $this is destroyed and there is, then no handle to retrieve.

Comment: Ignore my previous comments - I was misreading my own debugging code :) I think I sussed it out in the car on the drive home!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This all boils down to [refcounts](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) and how PHP treats [resources differently](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).

When a class instance is destroyed, all non-database link resources are closed (see above link on resources).  All non-resources referenced elsewhere will still be valid.

In your first example you assign `$temp = Foo::create(1)` which increases the refcount to an instance of `Foo`, preventing it from being destroyed which keeps the resource open.

In your second example, `var_dump( Foo::create(2)->bar()->handle );`, here's how things play out:

1. `Foo::create(2)` is called, creating an instance of `Foo`.
2. You call method `bar()` on the new instance, returning `$this` which increases the refcount by one.
3. You leave `bar()`'s scope and the next action isn't a method call or an assignment, refcount goes down by one.
4. The instance's refcount is zero, so it's destroyed.  All non-database link resources are closed.
5. You attempt to access a closed resource, returning `Unknown`.

As additional proof, this works just fine:

```
$temp = Foo::create(3)->bar();
// $temp keep's Foo::create(3)'s refcount above zero
var_dump( $temp->handle );
```

As does this:

```
$temp = Foo::create(4)->bar()->bar()->bar();
// Same as previous example
var_dump( $temp->handle );
```

And this:

```
// Assuming you made "id" public.
// Foo is destroyed, but "id" isn't a resource.  It will be garbage collected later.
var_dump( Foo::create(5)->id );
```

This *doesn't* work:

```
$temp = Foo::create(6)->handle;
// Nothing has a reference to Foo, it gets destroyed, all resources closed.
var_dump($temp);
```

Neither does this:

```
$temp = Foo::create(7);
$handle = $temp->handle;
unset($temp);
// $handle is now a reference to a closed resource because Foo was destroyed
var_dump($handle);
```

When `Foo` is destroyed, all open resources (except database links) are closed.  References other properties from `Foo` are still valid.

Demos:
https://eval.in/271514

Comment: In this case it was for a rather simple chainable OOP structure. Consider `SqlCommand::create()->select('foo')->from('bar')->where('foo.id = 3')->orderBy('foo.id ASC')->fetchRow()`. This works even though I technically haven't created an instance of the SqlCommand first. This also works for scalar values already, just not resources for whatever reason, so what's the reason it works for scalar values? Surely they don't increase/decrease the refcount any differently just because my last property is a scalar value rather than a resource?

Comment: Resources are a [special exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).
Database handles are an exception to the special exceptions.  I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that it's all about variable scoping.
>
> In short if you assign `Foo::create()` to a global variable you can
>   access the `handle` in the global scope and the destructor won't be
>   called until the end of the script.
>
> Whereas if you don't actually assign it to a global variable the last
>   method call in the local scope will trigger the destructor; the handle
>   is closed at `Foo::create(1)->bar()` so `->method` is now closed when
>   you're attempting to access it.

Further investigation reveals that premise is flawed - there's definitely something hinky going on here! It **only** seems to affect resources.

---

**case 1**

```
$foo = Foo::create(1);
var_dump( $foo->bar()->handle );
```

Results in:

```
resource(3) of type (stream)
```

In this case we have assigned the global variable `$foo` to be a new instance of `Foo` created with `Foo::create(1)`. We're now accessing that global variable with `bar()` to return itself and then the public `handle`.

---

**case 2**

```
$bar = Foo::create(2)->bar();
var_dump( $bar->handle );
```

Results in:

```
resource(4) of type (stream)
```

Again, it's still OK because `Foo::create(2)` has created a new instance of `Foo` and `bar()` has simply returned it (it still had access to it within the local scope). This has been assigned to the global variable `$bar` and it's from that, that `handle` is being retrieved.

---

**case 3**

```
var_dump( Foo::create(3)->bar()->handle );
```

Results in:

```
resource(5) of type (Unknown)
```

This is because when `Foo::create()` returns a new instance of `Foo`, that's used by `bar()`... however when `bar()` closes there's no longer any **local** use of that instance and the `__destruct()` method is called which closes the handle. It's the same result you'd get if you simply wrote:

```
$h = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
fclose($h);
var_dump($h);
```

You get exactly the same result if you try:

```
var_dump( Foo::create(3)->handle );
```

`Foo::create(3)` will call the destructor because there are no more local calls to that instance.

---

**EDIT**

Further tinkering has muddied the waters further...

I've added this method:

```
public function handle() {
    return $this->handle;
}
```

Now if my premise was right, doing:

```
var_dump( Foo::create(3)->handle() );
```

*should* have resulted in:

```
resource(3) of type (stream)
```

... but it doesn't, again you get a resource type of *Unknown* - it seems the destructor is called at `return $this` **before** the public class member is accessed! Yet it's absolutely fine to call a method on it:

```
public function handle() {
    return $this->bar();
}
```

That will quite happily give you your object back:

```
object(Foo)#1 (2) {
  ["id":"Foo":private]=>
  int(3)
  ["handle"]=>
  resource(3) of type (stream)
}
```

It seems there's no way to access resource class members, in this fashion, before the destructor is called?!

---

As **Alex Howansky** points out, it's fine with scalars:

```
public function __destruct() {
    $this->id = 2000;
    fclose($this->handle);
}

public function handle() {
    return $this->id;
}
```

Now:

```
var_dump( Foo::create(3)->handle() );
```

Results in:

```
int(3)
```

... the original $id was returned before the destructor was called.

This definitely smells like a bug to me.

Comment: There's still something wacky going on though. If you set handle to a scalar in the constructor, and then set it to null in the destructor, you'll get back the expected pre-nulled value when you reference it. This unsetting behavior only occurs when handle is a resource. I think it's a bug. If `$foo = new Foo(); echo $foo->bar;` behaves differently than `echo (new Foo())->bar;` then it makes the latter notation pretty useless.

Comment: Oh - it gets worse - just doing some further tinkering and now I'm even more confused; I'll update this...

Comment: Heh, it surely is. I didn't find anything in the bug tracker for it either.

Comment: Really great thoughts and tests - thank you so much for tinkering around with it. I thought it might be a bug too, but surely I can't be the only one to have made this rather simple code, and considering this bug has been in PHP for almost 10 years it just seems unlikely that no one else would've run into the same issue. Maybe they have and just couldn't be bothered figuring out *why*, though. I'm also no OPCODE person at all, but the only difference is `ASSIGN !0, $1`. [Works](http://3v4l.org/Hqeq2/vld#tabs) - [doesn't work](http://3v4l.org/l3bXE/vld#tabs)

Comment: Also note, while HHVM appears to work because it outputs "stream" instead of "unknown" -- you can't actually use the stream. It will fail with a warning about invalid stream resource. So it's consistent at least. :)